# Form submission error in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, forms

I'm going to submit a form in laravel

This is my form:

```
<form method="post" action="/Payment">
    <input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <ul class="form-style">
        <li><label>Mobile Number: <span class="required">*</span></label>
            <input type="text" name="number" class="field-divided"  />
        </li>
        <li>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">purchase</button>
        </li>
    </ul>
</form>
```

and this is the rout:

```
Route::post('/Payment','mainController@payment')->name('Payment');
```

and this is my controller:

```
class mainController extends BaseController {
    public function index() {
        return view('main');
    }

    public function payment(Request $request) {
        var_dump($request->all());
        die('here');
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ MethodNotAllowedHttpException
No message
```

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because your form data is not sent to payment method you should always use route name in form

change your action in form to : `{{ route('Payment')}`

delete :                     `<input name="_token" type="hidden" value="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>`

and replace : `@csrf` in form